# Mistake in display and insert methods (double-ended queue)

Tags: java, deque

1) My  problem

when i make remove from right or left program will be remove true
but when i call diplay method the content wrong

like this
I insert 12  43  65  23
and when make remove from left program will remove 12 
but when call display method show like this 12   43  65

and when make remove from right program will remove 23
but when call display method show like this 12  43

Why  ??????    );

and when i try  to make insert after remove write this

Can not insert right because the queue is full . first remove right and then u can insert right

where is the  problem  ??

Please  Help me

please

2) My  code

FIRST CLASS

```
class dqueue
{
    private int fullsize;                    //number of all cells
    private int item_num;                    // number of busy cells only
    private int front,rear;
    public int j;
    private double [] dqarr;
//==========================================
    public dqueue(int s)                      //constructor
    {
        fullsize = s;
        front = 0;
        rear = -1;
        item_num = 0;
        dqarr = new double[fullsize];
    }
//==========================================
    public void insert(double data)
    {
        if (rear == fullsize-1)
            rear = -1;
        rear++;
        dqarr[rear] = data;
        item_num++;

    }
   public double removeLeft() // take item from front of queue
     {
   double temp = dqarr[front++]; // get value and incr front
   if(front == fullsize) 
   front = 0;
   item_num --; // one less item
   return temp;
    }
    public double removeRight() // take item from rear of queue
     {
   double temp = dqarr[rear--]; // get value and decr rear
   if(rear == -1) // 
   rear = item_num -1;
   item_num --; // one less item
   return temp;
    }
//=========================================

     public void display ()                //display items
{
for (int j=0;j<item_num;j++)               // for every element 
System.out.print(dqarr[j] +"  " );          // display it 
System.out.println("");
}

//=========================================
public int size()              //number of items in queue
{
return item_num;
}
//==========================================
public boolean isEmpty()       // true if queue is empty
{
return (item_num ==0);
}


}
```

SECOND CLASS

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class dqueuetest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("              ***** Welcome here***** ");
        System.out.println("              *****  Mind Of Programming Group***** ");
       System.out.println("               _____________________________________________ ");
        System.out.println("enter size of your dqueue");
        int size = input.nextInt();
        dqueue mydq = new dqueue(size);
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("enter your itemes");
//=====================================
        for(int i = 0;i<=size-1;i++)
        {
           System.out.printf("item %d:",i+1);
           double item = input.nextDouble();
           mydq.insert(item);
           System.out.println("");
        }    

//=====================================  
int queue =size ;         
int c = 0 ;
while (c != 6)
{
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("************************************************");
    System.out.println("               MAIN MENUE");
    System.out.println("1- INSERT RIGHT  ");
    System.out.println("2- REMOVE LEFT");
    System.out.println("3- REMOVE RIGHT");
    System.out.println("4- DISPLAY");
    System.out.println("5- SIZE");
    System.out.println("6- EXIT");  
    System.out.println("************************************************");
    System.out.println("choose your operation by number(1-6)");  
    c = input.nextInt();
    switch  (c)
    {
    case 1:
   if (queue == size)
    System.out.print("Can not insert right because the queue is full . first remove right and then u can insert right   ");
          else { System.out.print("enter your item: ");
           double item = input.nextDouble();
           mydq.insert(item);}
          break;

   case 2:
       System.out.println("REMOVE FROM REAR :");
              if( !mydq.isEmpty() )
    {
  double item = mydq.removeLeft();

  System.out.print(item + "\t");
    } // end while
  System.out.println("");
  mydq.display();

    break;

   case 3:
    System.out.println("REMOVE FROM FRONT :");
            if( !mydq.isEmpty() )
    {
  double item = mydq.removeRight();

  System.out.print(item + "\t");
    } // end while
  System.out.println("");
  mydq.display();
     break;

    case 4:
    System.out.println("The items in Queue are :");  
        mydq.display();
    break;

    case 5:
     System.out.println("The  Size of the Queue is :"+mydq.size());
    break;

    case 6:
    System.out.println("Good Bye");

    break;

    default:
    System.out.println("wrong chiose enter again");
  }       //end switch
 }       //end while
}        // end main     

}//end class
```

Comment: Reformatted the code for you (still a mess, but less of a total mess than it used to be) and added the obviously missing java tag (the display tag makes absolutely no sense whatsoever but I don't understand what you mean well enough to help).  I recommend further editing and tag clarification to make this question less of a disaster, which it currently still is,

Comment: thanxs.

I have problem in display method
i remove from left but when I call display after remove I find element from right it is remove not left ^^

Comment: Too much crying for *help* and *???* in that question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that's what confusing you most is your `display` method...:

```
public void display ()                //display items
{
    for (int j=0;j<item_num;j++)               // for every element 
        System.out.print(dqarr[j] +"  " );          // display it 
    System.out.println("");
}
```

in this method you're completely ignored the "internal logical structure" of the queue you have coded, which depends crucially on the `front` and `rear` indices: indeed, note you don't even **mention** either of those indices here -- you just print the "physically first" `item_num` elements, which have no relationship whatsoever with the "logically present" ones.

You need, instead, to start with the `front`th element (**not** the `0`th one!) and show the `item_num` elements starting there (with wraparound at the end if you meet it, of course). This will display the *logical* contents of your queue instead of a "random-oid" slice of the array that implements it!-)

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of `display` iterates through the backing array from 0 until `item_num`, so it prints the wrong values. It should iterate from `front` to `rear` instead (with checks for wrapping the index around at the end of the buffer) to print out the *actual* contents of the queue:

```
public void display() {
  int j = front;
  for (int count = 0; count < item_num; count++) {
    System.out.print(dqarr[j] + "  ");
    j = increment(j);
  }
  System.out.println();
}

private int increment(int index) {
  if (index == fullsize - 1)
    return 0;
  return ++index;
}
```

I defined an `increment` method to implement the index stepping in one single place - you have this in multiple places within your code.

Further note that there is no overflow check in your implementation: if I add `fullsize + 1` elements to the queue, the first element will be silently overwritten.

**Update:** I realized that in your queue implementation `rear` indexes the last element of the queue (not the one *after* the last element, as is usual in dequeue implementations I have seen), so I modified the code example and my answer accordingly.

Comment: still there is problem
when i used your method display make remove from both right and rear
:(  :(
like this
i insert 12    34    45   67
and make remove from left
out put become like this  34    45 
):    ):

please help me

Answer (score 0):

If this is not homework and you're using Java 6 or newer, why not just use on the built-in [`Deque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html)s?

Those consist of [`ArrayDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html), [`LinkedList`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) (retrofitted with this interface in Java 6), and the concurrent [`LinkedBlockingDeque`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html).